# Why console.log receiver value in get handler cause an error?

Tags: es6-proxy

I am learning ES6 Proxy, and try to understand param 'receiver' in a get trap, so I tried to console.log the receiver value. But when run in nodeJS, it causes an error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```js
let proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get (target, key, receiver) {
    console.log('receiver:', receiver)
  }
})
let obj = Object.create(proxy)
console.log(obj)
```

I want to know what is causing this error, and how to test `receiver`'s reference in different situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `receiver` in `get (target, key, receiver)` refers to the Proxy object, so you create an endless loop.

`console.log(obj)` tries to log the contents of `obj`, so it is iterating over all its keys, and retrieves their value. To get their value, the `get` of the Proxy is invoked, and in that get you have `console.log('receiver:', receiver)`, and there `receiver` refers to `obj`, so again it tries to log the contents of `obj`, … which results in an endless recursive loop.

If you want to understand the param `receiver` in a get trap then you should not use logging, but the debugger, breakpoints, and the variable inspector in the debugger.

Comment: Node.js really outputs **Maximum call stack size exceeded**, V8 (I mean web implementations that uses V8) makes infinite loop with messages from console.log and never ends. But Gecko (Firefox) doesn't do infinite loop, it outputs only proxy object (proxy trap not involved).

I suspect V8 has an error in implementation proxy, I observed another strange things when I used console.log command into proxy trap in V8 engine.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the following code will help to solve your problem.

```
let proxy = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function (target, key, receiver) {
        console.log('receiver:' + receiver);
    }
});
let obj = Object.create(proxy);
console.log(obj);
```

Here you have create a Proxy object and it makes an infinite loop which never ends.

This error (maximum call stack trace exceed) means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit. This is almost always because of a recursive function with a base case that isn't being met.

+(string concatenation operator) with object will call the toString method on the object and a string will be returned. So, '' + object is equivalent to object.toString(). And toString on object returns "[object Object]".

With , the object is passed as separate argument to the log method. So, this takes much time to provide arguments to the console log by sepertely and makes a "maximum call stack trace exceed" error.

So according to me I hope that this shold be the issue.

Comment: And why do you think that this will solve the problem? You should add some explanation about it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind advise @t.niese.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** problem in implementation of `console.log` in the **chrome**/**node.js**

---

If we take your code and run in **firefox** we will see the next:

> Object {}

Yes, that's all what will output **firefox**.

You might ask the question: "What the matter?". We know that the same code in **chrome** and **node.js** makes *infinite loop* and *maximum callstack exceeded*.

---

**My view of the problem:**

Let's take a little edited example of your code:

```js
let proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get (target, key, receiver) {
    console.log(key)
  }
})
console.log(Object.create(proxy))
```

Let's see what it will output in the different environments:

**Chrome:**

> {} 
> Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) 
> **2** splice

**Node.js:**

> Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom) 
> Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) 
> {}

**Firefox:**

> Object {}

What a twist! Don't you think? Each platform has printed different results. And here we can conclude the only one thing: Every implementation has different behaviour API of the `console.log`.

Let's see another example:

```js
let proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get (target, key, receiver) {
    console.log(key)
  }
})
alert(Object.create(proxy))
```

In this example I've just changed API from `console.log` to `window.alert`. Well, go to see results of printing in different environments.

**Chrome:**

> Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive) 
> toString 
> valueOf 
> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value**

**Firefox:**

> Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive) 
> toString 
> valueOf 
> **Uncaught TypeError: can't convert Object.create(...) to string**

Wow, are you surprised? Same results in both browsers with different engines.

Whatwg doesn't specify how implementations should implement `console.log` API exactly, but `window.alert` has concrete steps and that why we got same results. And that inspite of `window.alert` algorithm doesn't reveal how it should convert arguments to string for printing to the screen in special alert box.

---

But I can explain how the last example works with proxy unlike with the `console.log`.

If you know how js works with objects when it try convert to primitive it will be piece of cake.

There is operation in ECMAScript that is called [ToString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring). When this operation is called (I guess that `window.alert` call it to convert its value to string) it runs in further the operation with the name [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) (this operation is achieved because, we have an object not a primitive value).

Following occurs the next:

1. The try to get from object `Symbol.toPrimitive` property with further its calling to receive its primitive value. If the result of calling `Symbol.toPrimitive` is object, then will be throw an error.
2. If `Symbol.toPrimitive` hasn't been found, then will be call [OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) (its order of performing depends on `hint`, in our case `hint` is `"string"` value)
3. If `hint` is `"string"` value then occurs searching and calling the following methods: `"toString"`, `"valueOf"`. If `hint` isn't `"string"` value then searching and calling is performed with: `"valueOf"`, `"toString"`.
4. If methods haven't been found or the last one from them returns object then throwing an error.

If the steps above doesn't invoke the error, then returns a primitive value.

So if you notice your attention to example with `window.alert`, you notice that the invocation of `window.alert` will be the cause of printing the methods that are definetely same as in [ToString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive): `Symbol.toPrimitive`, `"toString"`, `"valueOf"`. And the final is an error that messages about fail of conversion into string.

**Conclusion:** `console.log` has different implementation in engines, some implementation such as **chrome** inside `console.log` may use arguments directly, thats why we observe strange logging from **chrome** unlike **firefox**.